# Building a table with 3 columns, entry field fillable, and move over time or with a button,

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to build a table with 3 columns that will be able to be filled out with an entry field ( Name, Belt Rank, Weight Class). I am using HTML, PHP, and MYSQL. I have so far tried creating a database with SQL and running a program that I tried putting together but I suck at this. Here is the code that I have been trying to run but all it does is go to entry field, then after that, I get a page full of my PHP code. If anyone could help me I would appreciate that so much. If my code sucks I can throw it out if you got a better idea or direction to go.

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>Insert Form Data in MySQL Database Using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">

        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
                <br/>
        BeltRank: <input type="text" name="rank">
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Insert">            
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And for the PHP portion:

```
   <?php
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if(!$con)
{
 echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}
if (!mysqli_select_db ($con,'hawaii-masters'))
{
 echo 'Database Not Selected';
}



$Name = $_POST['name'];
$BeltRank = $_POST['rank'];

$sql = "insert into person (Name,BeltRank) values ('$Name','$BeltRank')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
 echo 'Not Inserted';
}
else
{
 echo 'Inserted Successfully';
}
header("refresh:2; url=index.html");
?>
```

Comment: please add screenshots or text output from browser. btw, the  do you have a running webserver?

Comment: php is a server-side language, you need to put your code in the webserver directory

Comment: Yes I am using XMAPP local for now.  I am not sure how to attach a screenshot but I can tell you that the browser text is the exact PHP code I have in the file. It looks like this on the browser.

Comment: I think I saved it in the correct place. Windows(C)>>xampp>>htdocs>>hawaii-masters ...I have my 2 code files stored with in the hawaii masters folder

Comment: My final goal for the project is to have this list be able to be moveable( from bottom up) with a button click and also have this list moving  over a distinguished time, example; Every 5 min the list will move one space up and the bottom row will be empty and ready two be filled by the field.

Comment: Did you start the Webserver-Service (Apache) in XAMPP-Controlpanel?

Comment: Is your file a *.php file?

Comment: Yes, the HTML is saved as index.html and the PHP is saved as insert.php. The Apache and MySQL are both running as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I will explain so that hopefully I can help someone in the future. So it had to do with my understanding of the server and the way the documents are stored. When I was running the file I was running it from the folder I had it saved in, Windows(C)>>xampp>>htdocs>>hawaii-masters but that is where I was getting my problem. I was able to get my entry fields to appear but then when I put the names inside of them and hit subimit I was redirected to another browser that only had my php code displayed.

So. When I tested my code by typing local/hawaii-masters into the browser I was greeted by the entry fields and when I submit it I was greeted with the correct submission. So there was nothing wrong with the posted code above.